# How to set a const to equal a field value?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a variable must be constant ( port number)
and I want it to equals a fields value (port_text)
I'm trying to do it this way:

```
    const int portNo = int.Parse(port_text.text);
```

but it says that the expression assigned to portNo must be constant...
Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't use a constant for that. Use a readonly field instead.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

Comment: @savanna: You can only use readonly for that as an initializer or in the class constructor.  Seems like an unlikely time to be assigning from a property.

Comment: The error seems rather self explanatory.  The value isn't constant, so you either need to assign a constant value instead or assign it to a non-constant identifier.  What's confusing about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const` keyword means that `portNo`'s value is fixed at *compile time*.

If you are assigning this in a class constructor (or as a field initializer, but this case seems less likely here), you can use `readonly` instead of `const`.

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

Otherwise, consider another way to address your need such as perhaps a public property with a private setter

```
public int PortNo { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`const` is used for **compile-time** constants. They cannot be assigned to expressions.

`readonly` is better, but it has to be assigned at instantiation time. There is no way you're text box will be populated in time for this; if it was, you might as well not use the text box!

You'll need to use a standard variable to store input from the UI. You can use a private setter in a property to make only that class be able to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign it a variable value.  Constants cannot be variable.  Check out the following link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx.  You could just use a variable integer like so:

```
int portNo = int.Parse(port_text.text);
```